# Cron not sending PHP email

Tags: php, email, cron

I have the following script:

```
<?
$dir = './var/session';
$fi = new FilesystemIterator($dir, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$fileCount = iterator_count($fi);

//    echo 'Directory Count: ';echo $fileCount;

//echo '<br />';



$bytes = 0;
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('./var/session') as $file) {
    if ($file->isFile()) {
        $bytes += $file->getSize();
    }
}

//echo $bytes;
//echo ' Bytes';
//echo '<br />';

 $MBbytes = number_format($bytes / 1048576, 2);
//echo $MBbytes;echo ' MB';



    $from = "mail@example.com";
    $to = "admin@example.com";
    $subject = "Session MB = " .$MBbytes;
    $message = "Session MB = " .$MBbytes."\n Directory Count: " .$fileCount;
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers,"-fmail@example.com");
//    echo "Email sent";
```

I'm trying to run this script by cron. When I run it by going to it in my browser it works fine. I've used every cron expression I can but the email doesn't get sent.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you confirmed the script is is being called? That's the first step so you know if it is a cron issue or a coding issue (or something after the code is run).

Comment: How can I confirm it?

Comment: An easy way is to write to a log file. If that file is not created or updated, the script is not being executed.

Comment: What cron expression are you using? That would probably help.

Comment: Currently trying this: * * * * * wget https://www.example.com/session-folder-size.php

Comment: I created a log file but it's empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this: 
*/10 * * * * php LOCALPATHTOYOURSCRIPT/session-folder-size.php

where */10 * * * * - “At every 10th minute.”

Comment: I'm running this now * * * * * php /home/xxxxx/public_html/session-folder-size.php but no emails are sent . I was logging it as suggested and the log file had the exact php script i.e. in session-folder-size.php

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Wget was being blocked by an htaccess rule.  I noticed in the log file a 403 error. Don't know why it doesn't run using php...

Thanks John Conde for the log file tip.

Comment: because you have different PHP settings for CLI and WebServer for example